# Check whether current focus is in editor or not in Thunderbird

Tags: javascript, xul, thunderbird

I want to check whether the current focus is in editor or not at the compose screen in Thunderbird.

I tried below code but it is giving me `null` instead of object of that focused element.

**XUL**

```
<editor type="content-primary" id="content-frame" src="about:blank"
        name="browser.message.body" flex="1" context="msgComposeContext"/>
```

**JS**

```
alert(document.commandDispatcher.focusedElement);
```

I want to check whether the current focus is on `editor` (body area) or not. How can I get the currently focused element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I got the answer. You can check using below code.

```
document.activeElement.id
```